# Insert array list variable into MySQL using Python

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I having problem to insert list of array using variable into MySQL.

Below is my code:-

```
import MySQLdb as sql

def upload():
    fopen = open(r"C:\scms\files\input\HHT\VG14SHDR.dat", 'r')

    # prepare ready file
    for line in fopen:
        arropen = line.strip(',')

        var1 = arropen[0:1]
        var2 = arropen[1:10]
        var3 = arropen[11:20]

db = sql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="123", db="test")
cur = db.cursor()

#create query
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO contacts(`id`)(%s)""", values1)


db.commit()
db.close()

upload()
```

if i print var1 as below:-

```
I
I
C
C
D
D
```

i want this insert into 1 column in each row in database

Hope guys understand what i mean it.
Please help.

Comment: Where does the `values1` come from?

Comment: You probably mean `cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO contacts(`id`) VALUES (%s)""", var1)`...

Comment: sorry, wrong type, yes, actually var1, but got error when run it. error shows that can't define variable var1.

Comment: anyone cal help me on this problem..please